# Error Exception: Not found createPDF @ Create PDFs.gs:25

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function createPDF() {
  let Naam = "aaa";
  let Geboortedatum = "bbb";
  let Contactpersoon = "ccc";
  let Tel = "12345678";
  let Mail = "cc@dd.ee";
  let Naam1 = "fff";
  let Naam2 = "ggg";
  let Telefoon1 = "hhh";
  let Telefoon2 = "iii";
  let Graag = "jjj";
  let Goed = "kkk";
  let Interesse = "lll";
  let Ouders = "mmm";
  let Getuigschrift = "nnn";
  let Noden = "mmm";
  let Toelichting = "ooo";
  let Fase0 = "ppp";
  let Fase1 = "qqq";
  let Fase2 = "rrr";
  let Fase3 = "sss";
  const DocFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxx");
  const Tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("yyy");
  const tempFile = DocFile.makeCopy(Tempfolder);
  const tempDocFile = SlidesApp.openById(tempFile.getId);
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Naam}", Firstname);
  body.replaceText("{Geboortedatum}", Geboortedatum);
  body.replaceText("{Contactpersoon}", Contactpersoon);
  body.replaceText("{Tel}", Tel);
  body.replaceText("{Mail}", Mail);
  body.replaceText("{Naam1}", Naam1);
  body.replaceText("{Naam2}", Naam2);
  body.replaceText("{Telefoon1}", Telefoon1);
  body.replaceText("{Telefoon2}", Telefoon2);
  body.replaceText("{Graag}", Graag);
  body.replaceText("{Goed}", Goed);
  body.replaceText("{Interesse}", Interesse);
  body.replaceText("{Ouders}", Ouders);
  body.replaceText("{Getuigschrift}", Getuigschrift);
  body.replaceText("{Noden}", Noden);
  body.replaceText("{Toelichting}", Toelichting);
  body.replaceText("{Fase0}", Fase0);
  body.replaceText("{Fase1}", Fase1);
  body.replaceText("{Fase2}", Fase2);
  body.replaceText("{Fase3}", Fase3);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
}
```

Why can't he find the slide I just copied? I do have API enabled and I have the rights on the copy, since I just made cet copy... There is an error in line 25, but I can't seem to find out what it is...

```
const tempDocFile = SlidesApp.openById(tempFile.getId);
```

I followed this link to get where I am now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ&t=579s.
Please help me out!
Thank you

Comment: I'm not going to watch a video just to answer a question.

Answer (score 2):

The error is here: `const tempDocFile = SlidesApp.openById(tempFile.getId()); const body = tempDocFile.getBody();`

Class Presentation has no method getBody();

[Class Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation)

I would also guess that you're identification of the error is incorrect.

I'm guessing that you meant to use DocumentApp rather than SlidesApp.

Comment: If I simplify the code: and use Documentapp, I get the following error: **Exception: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
createPDF @ Create PDFs.gs:7** ```.....
  const Tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1piwj3iHuD6XHTIe1eAKT6oGszOqlKdVn");
  const tempFile = DocFile.makeCopy(Tempfolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId);
...```

Comment: I just noticed that your `tempFile.getId()` is missing the parenthesis.  It's a very common mistake with the new editor.